# Best practices for hiding/showing of controls when dropDrownList changes in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

So far I am hiding/showing controls after dropDownList changes index using 'DropDownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged'. And as far as I know this hiding/showing will always trip to server and I read on other tips that this is a bad practice.

I know how to hide/show controls using jQuery/javaScript, but my question is, what if the user's browser has disabled the javascript? How can I hide/show controls that if the client side works the server side will not be trigger, and if the client side fails the server side will be run. I hope I made my question clear. :(

Thanks for all the advices.. Sorry for being a newbie.

Comment: I seriously doubt 'DropDownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged' works when you turn off JavaScript. Why don't you try that and return to the question to see if you want to rework it.

Comment: @ErikReppen: `DropDownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged` is a server-side  event.  It requires a postback.  It *doesn't* require Javascript.  Hence, the OP's question is, how can I make it work on the client if Javascript is enabled, and work on the server if it isn't.

Comment: Oh we're way back in pre-ajax webforms.

Comment: Why do you have to support clients who disabled js?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are you sure? For `DropDownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged` to trigger, the client needs to post back when the select is changed, using JavaScript - it's just that .Net handles this. Unless you have a submit button, but then a different event will fire.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, indeed, the `SelectedIndexChanged` server event. But it shouldn't be fired automatically with turned off javascript.